# what are some ways to store information mechanically?

Tags: science-based, computers

what are some ways to store largish amounts of information mechanically? What would a mechanical computer use for memory storage if it was entirely mechanical?

edit: guys why is this downvoted? I don't mean to sound annoyed but can the downvoters please comment and explain the purpose, as I am unaware of the cause.

Comment: Babbage designed his [difference engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) and [analytical engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_engine) in the first half of the 19th century. And [Jacquard looms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquard_machine) with their purely mechanical punched cards / punched tape read-only memory automated weaving textiles with complex pattern were introduced **in actual for-real industrial use** in 1804. I would say that this is pretty much a solved problem, and it was solved two centuries ago.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_computer

Answer (score 7):

**Punch Cards**

[Punched cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card) was the standard before magnetic storage

[image]

A program was made of a stack of these cards which would be fed into the computer. Being holes, these could be read by pins instead of lights.

The [Pianola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Player_piano) (player piano) used rolls of paper or metal with punched holes in a purely mechanical system to play music.

Comment: I am not sure which gives the better bits-per-cubic-foot, punch cards or paper tape. A foot of paper tape and a punch card each have a capacity of 960 bits. Paper tape might be harder to read mechanically.

Answer (score 2):

Konrad Zuse built a mechanical computer in 1941
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_(computer)

Charles Babbage's much eariler design for the analytical was never realised.

Herr Zuse's machine stored variable data by moving metal pins between two rest positions.

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3350972
(the red part here is the pin, and the ends of the C shaped track are the two rest positions)

Answer (score 2):

**Records!**

[image: record ad]

http://www.ordinarythrills.com/ordinarythrills/blog/2015/12/28/records-and-record-players-for-beginners
They are making a comeback, I understand.  The information on a record is stored as microscopic bumps, which can be mechanically turned directly into sound as a needle passes over them.  You do not need electricity to make a functioning phonograph.  Recent records are vinyl but earlier 72 rpm records were a brittle but durable ceramic. I think these clay discs retained fidelity longer than the sub sequent vinyl.

You could have the data records handled by a jukebox.

[image: jukebox]
https://www.shpock.com/en-gb/i/XRibVV5AmxZldnxE/rock-ola-469-jukebox

If only a machine handles the discs you reduce the chance for scratches and dirt, which is what shortens the operating life of records.  As far as the data format there is no reason you could not use fax machine language or even morse code.

Answer (score 1):

You can store memory in any system with multiple discrete states. One possible setup would be switches that are flipped to encode binary data- of course, this would be highly inefficient in terms of space and materials, but you could store anything you could on a computer.